# How to extract numeric values from a column in SQL

Tags: sql, numeric

I am trying to extract only the numeric values from a column that contains cells that are exclusively numbers, and cells that are exclusively letter values, so that I can multiply the column with another that contains only numeric values. I have tried

```
SELECT trim(INTENT_VOLUME) 
from A
WHERE ISNUMERIC(INTENTVOLUME)
```

and also

```
SELECT trim(INTENT_VOLUME) 
from A
WHERE ISNUMERIC(INTENTVOLUME) = 1
```

and neither works. I get the error Function `ISNUMERIC(VARCHAR)` does not exist. Can someone advise? Thank you!

Comment: Please tag the DBMS, sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on DBMS.

in SqlServer you have a limited built-in features to do it, so the next query may not work with all variants of your data:

```
select CAST(INTENT_VOLUME AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) 
from A 
where INTENT_VOLUME LIKE '%[0-9.-]%'
and INTENT_VOLUME NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%';
```

In Oracle you can use regex in a normal way:

```
select to_number(INTENT_VOLUME) 
from A 
where REGEXP_LIKE(INTENT_VOLUME,'^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$');
```

MySQL DBMS has also built-in regex

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which tests if that text value can be cast as numeric...

select intent_volume
from a
where (intent_volume ~ '^([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$') = 't'